# How to handle 1 million requests with node using nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

This is a question that i encountered during an interview and i was not sure how to approach a problem like this as i have never faced such a situation. I went on to say that we can use the `cluster module` to leverage the cpu and also if there are any cpu intensive tasks we could make use of the `child_process module`. But these were not what the interviewer was generally interested in. After the interview was over i got a chance to speak to the interviewer about that question and he told me that there is an nginx configuration can help address these issues. 
Can anyone point me to a right direction so i can study about such problems and what an Application Architect should know in general.